# Mortgage calculator, unable to use variables as integers, to do math formula

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am trying to make a application to calculate mortgage, (I got motivated to do so, from a question earlier, on here). But, it seems as thought it won't work. The problem I'm having is that I am unable to provide the calculations function the 3 inputs, p, i, n, which I get from the Entry option in tkinter.

```
import time
from tkinter import *


class MortgageCalc:
    def __init__(self, master):
        global p, i, n

        p = IntVar()
        i = IntVar()
        n = IntVar()

        self.clock = Label(master, font=("times", 20, "bold"), bg="white")
        self.clock.pack(side='bottom', anchor='e')
        self.tick()

        self.title = Label(master, text="Welcome to Dev's Mortgage Calculater!", font=("times", 23, "bold"), bg="aqua")
        self.title.pack(anchor=W)

        self.title = Label(master, text="Enter the information below to calculate your mortgage.", font=("times", 18), bg="aqua")
        self.title.pack(anchor=W)

        self.P = Entry(master, width=60, textvariable=p)
        self.P.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

        self.I = Entry(master, width=60, textvariable=i)
        self.I.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

        self.N = Entry(master, width=60, textvariable=n)
        self.N.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

        self.calcMortgage = Button(master, text='Calculate Monthly Mortgage Payment', font=10, fg='green', command=self.calculations, width=30, height=2)
        self.calcMortgage.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

        self.monthlyPayment = Label(master, text="Your monthly mortgage payment is", font=("times", 20, "bold"), bg="white")
        self.monthlyPayment.pack()
        self.calculations()

    def tick(self):
        time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.clock.config(text=time_string)
        self.clock.after(200, self.tick)

    def calculations(self):
        global p, i, n

        p = p.get()
        i = i.get()
        n = n.get()

        divide1 = p * (i * (1 + i) ** n)
        divide2 = ((1 + i) ** n - 1)
        payment = divide1 / divide2
        self.monthlyPayment.config(text=str(payment))


root = Tk()
root.title("Dev's Mortgage Calculator")
root.geometry('1025x750')
Tk = MortgageCalc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I get this error, before the window even opens!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/muhmm/PycharmProjects/untitled2/da.py", line 60, in <module>
    Tk = MortgageCalc(root)
  File "C:/Users/muhmm/PycharmProjects/untitled2/da.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.calculations()
  File "C:/Users/muhmm/PycharmProjects/untitled2/da.py", line 53, in calculations
    payment = divide1 / divide2
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

And, the problem is in the calculations function, as if I remove the code from there, and put "pass", the application runs completely fine.

And just so this makes sense, p is the amount you borrowed, i is the monthly interest, n is the number of payments over the life of the loan.

Comment: the error is clear I believe, that you can't divide by 0

Comment: There is no division by 0, as no value has been assigned to the variables. I think the python is automatically trying to do the math before the program even starts... And, before it does the math needed to get divide1 and divide2...

Comment: Well, you call `self.calculations()` at the end of `__init__`. At that moment no values are filled in, so the divisor is zero.

Comment: Anyway, it is good practise to 1) check the validity of the values, 2) cope with unusual  values. In this case, if `n<=0` there is no valid answer, if `i==0`, the answer would be `payment = p/n`

Comment: Another problem is that you use the same name for your values as for your input boxes. If you write `p = p.get()`, the second time you call `self.calculations` you get an error, because p isn' the inputbox anymore but just an integer. Best not use 'global' but also make p,i,n class variables as in:  `self.p = IntVar()`. Also, if `i` is an integer, it should be divided by 100 to get a reasonable percentage. And even then, it makes more sense to let it be a number with one or two decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `self.calculations()` from `def __init__` because it causes a division by 0.

Then, assuming you want all values to be integers, I changed :

```
p = p.get()
i = i.get()
n = n.get()
```

into

```
p = int(self.P.get())
i = int(self.I.get()) / 100
n = int(self.N.get())
```

because you were not getting the values of from the text fields and "i" was not divided by 100 to make it a scalar from 0 to 1 (which I think should be the case in your formula)

I haven't checked your monthly formula but I think it should be:

```
divide2 = ((1 + i) ** (n - 1))
```

and add @MasterOfTheHouse's suggestion and it should be fine!

Comment: Thanks, for for the fix in the formula, plus the .get stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You should have other issues there (besides the zero division) . Just make a check like this one and then look for the other issues.

```py
payment = 0 if divide2 == 0 else divide1/divide2
```

This quick-fix worked for me

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that test should be `payment = 0 if n == 0 else p/n if i == 0 else divide1/divide2`

Comment: I didn't mark your as the check, as the other guy was more in-depth. But, he also mentioned your answer in his answer, anyway I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad that it helped